# creating and working with a large 2 dimensional dataset in android

Tags: android, database

ok i have an sql database (we'll call it DATABASE1) that receives inputs of names from the user and they can input as many as they want.. what i need to do now is hard code a database or spreadsheet or matrix or something (we will call it DATASET1) that DATABASE1 can work with.. however the thing is is that DATASET1 is comprised of names of groups and each group contains a group of people.. think of DATASET1 as something like this..

group 1   =   "john"   "jim    "joe"   "ryan"   "luke"
group 2   =   "jim"    "bob"   "tim"
group 3   =   "blake"  "john"  "bill"  "frank"
...
...
...

so as you can see each group is a different set of names and there is no defined number for how many names are in each group.. now what i need to accomplish is that DATASET1 needs to work with DATABASE1 (which by the way will end up being very large.. it will start at 200 groups but will only continue to get bigger with updates.. probably in the thousands) and check for subsets.. my program needs to browse DATASET1 and take each group and see if it is a subset of DATABASE1 in the fastest/most efficient way possible.. anyone have any ideas about an approach?

Answer (score 0):

Create a realtional database in SQLite:

Tables:

```
groups (id, name)
```

id - prikary key
name - name of a group

```
group_names (id, group_id, name)
```

id - prikary key
group_id references groups.id; this column should also have an index
name - name like "jim", "blake"

Is name order relevant?

Comment: no name order isnt relevant.. but with a sqlite database (which is what im using for DATABASE1) it has to be hard coded into the program (doesnt it?).. is that the fastest way of working with a large amount of data? and also how do i go about checking for the subset after ive created my sql database for the groups and their corresponding list of names in each?

Comment: 1. What is an initial state of DATABASE1? Is it empty or already filled with data? 2. Any operations of retreiving data require basic knowledge of SQL.

Comment: 1) DATABASE1 is initially empty however it wont be compared to DATASET1 until the user inputs names.. 2) and well it looks like im going to have to learn something new.. i literally started programming like 2 weeks ago but i'd say ive amassed quite a bit of android programming in that time..  where should i start/what specifically do i need to learn to accomplish what i need to do?